# динамические массивы

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать данную задачу:Изначально не известно сколько пользователь введет чисел и когда он закончил вводить ,мы фиксируем количество введенных чисел и заполняем введенными числами массив.Например введено 12 23 45 67 78 900. Всего введено 6 чисел и на выходе мы имеем массив из этих чисел.Нужно реализовать без  использования векторов и классов ,только базовые понятия.Можно использовать динамический массив.заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что здесь нужно создавать доп-масив и в него копировать старый удаляя доп-массив. Но не выходит реализовать в коде.

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Еще, непонятно, когда заканчивать читать. В конце строки?

Comment: Ну вот почему люди считают, что классы в с++ не относятся к базовым понятиям. Вектор это и есть динамический массив.

Comment: Самый сложный вопрос — как определить, что пользователь закончил вводить числа :) Как только вы это укажете, можно решать. А пока требуется ИИ, который читает мысли пользователя и понимает, что вот, это число — последнее, можно больше не ждать. И еще — С++ без векторов и классов — это практически С, так может, стоит изменить язык в вопросе?

Comment: вопрос остается открытым - а классы/шаблоны все ещё можно использовать?

Answer (score 1):

#### Код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define KEY_ENTER 13

int main()
{
    string input;
    int len = 0;
    int* arr = new int[0];
    while (true) {
        if (_kbhit()) { // Когда клавиша нажата
            int code = _getch(); // получаем код клавиши
            if (code == KEY_ENTER) {
                int inputLen = input.size(); 
                cout << endl;
                if (inputLen != 0) { // Если ничего не ввели
                    // Добовляем input в arr
                    len++;
                    int* lastArr = arr;
                    arr = new int[len];
                    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
                    {
                        arr[i] = lastArr[i];
                    }
                    arr[len - 1] = stoi(input); // string -> int
                } else {
                    // выводим массив
                    cout << "Array:";
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        cout << " " << arr[i];
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
                input = ""; // сбравываем input
            }else{
                input += (char)code; // добовляем нажатую клавишу к input
                cout << (char)code; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Что бы закончить ввод массива надо нажать Enter, не вводя число

#### Результат:

```
10
20
5

Array: 10 20 5
```

Comment: Спасибо  вам большое

Comment: ой ой. код сильно завязан только на windows, ручное перекладывание и отсутствие проверки ошибок....

Comment: ДА, на маке не работает)к сожалению

Comment: вот вот. но тут все просто - хороший ответ - получи минус от анонимного минусатора, сомнительный ответ - получи плюсик. красота:)

Comment: @Глеб Что именно на маке не работает? `Enter` не нажимается или еще что-то? PS: если надо то проверку на неправильно введенные данные могу добавить

Comment: уже разобрался.спасибо